# Style based on category

Tags: css, wordpress

I can't quite seem to get the hover to change colour based on the category the post is tagged in.

I've added both body_class() and post_class() to the header.php as well as adding a function that adds the current post's category back to the body class -

```
add_filter('body_class','add_category_to_single');
function add_category_to_single($classes) {
    if (is_single() ) {
       global $post;
         foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category) {
              $classes[] = 'category-'.$category->slug;
         }
     }
return $classes;
  }
```

I'm able to change the hover on all the posts by using this styling -

```
.portfolio .portfolio-item:hover > .hover-item{
     background-color:#000000;
 }
```

but when I add the category class nothing happens. For example -

```
catergory-classes .portfolio-item:hover > .hover-item{
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Here is my [site.](http://tinyurl.com/nbhrmcl) Any help gratefully appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to make this change on the home page?

Comment: @rnevius  I am, yes. Just on the home page

Comment: Why has this received a downvote? I've shown all my workings out and was clear with what I am asking

Answer (score 0):

i think you for get to put a point at the first of css code
your css is

```
catergory-classes .portfolio-item:hover > .hover-item{
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

but correct is

```
.catergory-classes .portfolio-item:hover > .hover-item{
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a dot (.)

```
.catergory-classes .portfolio-item:hover > .hover-item{
background-color:#000000;}
```

And if the `.catergory-classes` and `.portfolio-item` needs to be applied on the same tag , then it should be (no spaces b/w 2 classes)

```
.catergory-classes.portfolio-item:hover > .hover-item{
background-color:#000000;}
```

Comment: I've tried it every way; with a dot, without a dot, hashtag... none of it works

Comment: Try with !important property of css ... might work..
.catergory-classes.portfolio-item:hover > .hover-item{
background-color:#000000 !important; }

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be setting a body class, since this will be the category of the front page itself (and won't change for each item). Instead, consider adding classes to the portfolio items (within The Loop). For example:

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $category = ! empty( $categories ) ? 'category-' . $categories[0]->name : '';
?>
    <li class="portfolio-content">
        <div class="portfolio-item <?php echo $category; ?>">
            <!-- Additional Content -->
        </div>
    </li>
```

You can then target these categories with:

```
.portfolio-item.category-somecategory:hover > .hover-item { }
```

Comment: I tried doing something similar along those lines and it removed the hover completely from the homepage. Just tried using yours and it did the same. Puzzling